# Creating a dictionary from a file and getting error

Tags: python, slice

I'm trying to get a dictionary that has patient IDS as the key and the name as the value however, need to find the last name and the first name and combine them as the value but I keep getting this error.

```
fhand = open('PatientsNames.txt')
fhand.readline()

patientinfo = dict()

for line in fhand:

    ids=line[:8]
    if ids not in patientinfo:
        patientinfo=[ids]
    endlastname = line[' ':8]
    lastname = line[8:endlastname]
    firstname = line[endlastname+1:]
    patientinfo[ids]=lastname + ',' + firstname
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alexs/PycharmProjects/Hwk13_Application2_STARTER/Hwk13a_STARTER.py", line 23, in <module>
    endlastname = line[' ':8]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: what did you want with endlastname? what is the file format?

Comment: `line[' ':8]` is invalid since string indices must be integers. Did you want `line.index(' ')`? BTW welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I recommend using a context manager to handle your file. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. It would also help if you could share some of the data, and explain what you’re trying to do. As it stands, certain aspects of your program don’t make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that when you wrote `endlastname = line[' ':8]` you were trying to get the index of the first `' '` occurring after index 8. In that case, we can replace the line you used with:

```
endlastname = line.find(' ', 8)
```

As for making new entries into the dictionary, that should be done in one line. The line you were using for a new entry—`patientinfo=[ids]`—was replacing the dictionary with a list containing only the `ids` value. Instead, we'll get the `id` and `lastname`/`firstname` values, then populate the dictionary in one line:

```
patientinfo[id] = lastname + ', ' + firstname
```

Putting that all together:

```
patientinfo = {}
lines = open('PatientsNames.txt').read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
    id=line[:8]
    if id not in patientinfo:
        endlastname = line.find(' ', 8)
        lastname = line[8:endlastname]
        firstname = line[endlastname+1:]
        patientinfo[id] = lastname + ', ' + firstname
```

In your case, it's not necessary to use the `str.find()` function, as we can instead just split the `line` around the `' '` using `str.split()`:

```
...
    if id not in patientinfo:
        patientinfo[id] = ', '.join(line[8:].split())
```

Note that you do not *need* to put the character to split around (`' '`) in the `split()` function explicitly, as that is the default value for `split()`.

Comment: It would make more sense to use `str.split`, i.e. `lastname, firstname = line[8:].split()`

Comment: @wjandrea Sure, but at least this way OP learns how to actually do the search he was trying to do. I'll add an edit with `.split()`.

Comment: @wjandrea Of course there is the obvious downside of not properly parsing an input name like `"Jones James Earl"`

Comment: And "Ó Briain Dara" (Dara Ó Briain) for that matter. But at least the code will error for faulty inputs like that. Ultimately the solution is not to use plaintext to store names, but that's beyond the scope of this thread. related: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)